# How to access repository from IRouter

Tags: entity-framework-core, aspnetboilerplate

I'm developing modular application and I'd like for entities from different modules to be able to register their own friendly url slugs.

```
app.UseMvc(routes =>
{
    routes.Routes.Add(new SlugRouter(routes.DefaultHandler));
    (...)
});
```

But following code throws **Cannot access a disposed object. Object name: 'CommerceDbContext'.** when trying to access slug from the repository.

```
public class SlugRouter : IRouter
{
    private readonly IRouter _target;

    public SlugRouter(IRouter target)
    {
        _target = target;
    }

    public async Task RouteAsync(RouteContext context)
    {
        var slugRepository = context.HttpContext.RequestServices.GetService<IRepository<SlugEntity>>();

        // ERROR: Cannot access a disposed object. Object name: 'CommerceDbContext'
        var urlSlug = await slugRepository.GetAllIncluding(x => x.EntityType).FirstOrDefaultAsync(x => x.Slug == context.HttpContext.Request.Path.Value);
        (...)
    }
```

It must be something simple I'm missing to be able to access the repository from router. Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Begin a [unit of work](https://aspnetboilerplate.com/Pages/Documents/Unit-Of-Work):

```cs
public async Task RouteAsync(RouteContext context)
{
    var slugRepository = context.HttpContext.RequestServices.GetService<IRepository<SlugEntity>>();
    var unitOfWorkManager = context.HttpContext.RequestServices.GetService<IUnitOfWorkManager>();

    using (var uow = unitOfWorkManager.Begin())
    {
        var urlSlug = await slugRepository.GetAllIncluding(x => x.EntityType).FirstOrDefaultAsync(x => x.Slug == context.HttpContext.Request.Path.Value);
        await uow.CompleteAsync();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Access IModel. You do not need dbContext for.

> for entities from different modules to be able to register their own
>   friendly url slugs

I do it this way:

1) move OnModelCreating to static methiod

```
    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        BuildModel(modelBuilder);
    }

    public static void BuildModel(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        // ...
    }
```

2) Create model where you need:

```
        var conventionSet = new ConventionSet();
        var modelBuilder = new ModelBuilder(conventionSet);
        AdminkaDbContext.BuildModel(modelBuilder);
        var mutableModel = modelBuilder.Model;
```

There is your meta (in mutableModel ). You can loop through entities (types of entities).